# Session en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sesiones

Tengo una duda referente a las sesiones que se vencen en Laravel, como sabran en el  archivo session.php hay una variable que se llama lifetime que alli se configura el tiempo en el que se desea que una sesion este viva.

El asunto que no se como hacer es que si la sesion se vence o se muera autamaticamente se vaya al login y se cierre la aplicacion.

Por que les pregunto esto? porque sucede que tengo un dashboard y cuando la sesion se muere al hacer clic en alguno de los enlaces del dashboard lo que me sale es una ventana para que ingrese usuario y clave, al ingresar usuario y clave me muestra la vista que acaba de clicar...

Ej: estaba clicando un enlace a Usuarios y como la sesion murio me muestra ventana de usuario y clave...

Pero cuando hago clic en ese enlace no me muestra nada de informacion, revisando los registros en la consola del navegador veo que el XSFR-TOKEN tambien muere y la unica forma de que todo funcione a la normalidad es refrescando todo el sitio.

Entonces lo que estoy buscando es que si se murio la sesion se redireccione de inmediato a login..

El asunto es: Existe alguna funcionalidad de Laravel que yo pueda decirle:

Si Session esta muerta entonces ir a Login??? no se si me explico.

Espero me puedan ayudar con esta...muchas gracias.

Comment: hola, lograste encontrar una solución? estoy buscando y no hay mucha info, me pasa lo mismo que tu caso en ese entonces

Answer (score -2):

Si realizaste el login con la documentación de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication 
es necesario agregar en cada uno de tus controladores el constructor para auth:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco por qué ésta es una solución al problema? Las respuestas que sólo dicen *añade estre trozo de código* deben evitarse porque lo importante es saber el por qué el problema ocurre

Comment: Yo tengo otro problema de pronto me da error 419